# Whats the best charts jQuery plugin to use on my App?

Tags: jquery, chars

**Hi all,**
i'm making an application based on **jQuery** and i need the **best charts plugin** to show the information to the client.
My app is litteraly like **Google AdWords** and **Google AdSense**. I need to show to the costumers the clicks and views per ad or banner on the last month or week, show the amount of credits to them and interact with our other service too.

I've googled for some plugins, allmost all of them are good, but i wan't to use the **best and easy to work**.

Can anybody advice me?

**Thanks in advance**,
José Moreira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) is my favorite. This is not jQuery plugin but pure javascript. Works good with all libraries.

Comment: Did anyone mentioned something about licenses?

Comment: Cool, very intuitive,   
it works with jQuery or MooTools, thats good ;) +1 for the choice, i will analyze it. About the licenses questions, anyone fits, but free is better ;)

Answer (score 4):

Again, not JQuery, but I'd go for [Google charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) - really easy to get started, lots of options. Update (Feb 2012): now there's [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/) which has evolved into the rather amazing and self-contained [D3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/).

Comment: The problem using Google Charts, is that makes me dependent of Google, any problem on google server or if that api is removed, i'm literaly f***ed :P
But it is very cool, but besides that i prefer flot or highcharts because their interface. +1

Comment: Agree with the Google-dependent issue. Let's hope if Google becomes fully evil that someone will reverse-engineer...

Answer (score 2):

I can strongly recommend [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) for that purpose. Easy to use, good results, sensible defaults.